# How do I fix these errors? CS50 Pset1 Credit

Tags: c, cs50

Can anyone please help me w/ this? Here is my code and the checking mistakes I got. Not really understand what's the problem and why there are issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)

{
    
    long long card;
    do
    {
    card = get_long_long("Card Number: ");
    }
    while (card < 0);

    long long int card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8;
    
    card1 = ((card%100)/10)*2;
    card2 = ((card%10000)/1000)*2;
    card3 = ((card%1000000)/100000)*2;
    card4 = ((card%100000000)/10000000)*2;
    card5 = ((card%10000000000)/1000000000)*2;
    card6 = ((card%1000000000000)/100000000000)*2;
    card7 = ((card%100000000000000)/10000000000000)*2;
    card8 = ((card%10000000000000000)/1000000000000000)*2;
    
    card1 = (card1%100)/10 + (card1%10);
    card2 = (card2%100)/10 + (card2%10);
    card3 = (card3%100)/10 + (card3%10);
    card4 = (card4%100)/10 + (card4%10);
    card5 = (card5%100)/10 + (card5%10);
    card6 = (card6%100)/10 + (card6%10);
    card7 = (card7%100)/10 + (card7%10);
    card8 = (card8%100)/10 + (card8%10);
    
    long long int card9, card10, card11, card12, card13, card14, card15, card16;
    
    card9 = (card%10);
    card10 = (card%1000)/100;
    card11 = (card%100000)/10000;
    card12 = (card%10000000)/1000000;
    card13 = (card%1000000000)/100000000;
    card14 = (card%100000000000)/10000000000;
    card15 = (card%10000000000000)/1000000000000;
    card16 = (card%1000000000000000)/100000000000000;
    
    long long int sum1, sum2, sum3;
    
    sum1 = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5 + card6 + card7 + card8;
    sum2 = card9 + card10 + card11 + card12 + card13 + card14 + card15 + card16;
    sum3 = sum1 + sum2;
    
    long long length = 0;
    long long visa = card;
    long long amex = card;
    long long master = card;
    
    if (sum3 % 10 != 0)
    
    {
        printf("%s\n", "INVALID CARD");
        return 0;
    }
   
    while (card>0)
    {
        card = card/10;
        length++;
    }
    
    //if VISA
    
    while (visa >= 10)
    {
        visa /= 10;
    }
    if (visa == 4 && (length == 13 || length == 16))
    
    {
        printf("%s\n","VISA");
        return 0;
    }
    
    //if AMEX
    
    while (amex >= 100000000000000)
    {
        amex /= 100000000000000;
    }
    if ((amex == 34 || amex == 37) && (length == 15))
    
    {
        printf("%s\n","AMERICAN EXPRESS");
        return 0; 
    }
    
    //if MASTER
    
    while (master >= 100000000000000)
    {
        master /= 100000000000000;
    }
        if ((master == 51 || master == 52 || master == 53 || master == 54 || master == 55) && (length == 16))
    
    {
        printf("%s\n","MASTERCARD");
        return 0; 
    }
     
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID CARD\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
}
```

```
:) credit.c exists

:) credit.c compiles

:( identifies 378282246310005 as AMEX
    expected "AMEX\n", not "INVALID CARD\n..."

:( identifies 371449635398431 as AMEX
    expected "AMEX\n", not "INVALID CARD\n..."

:) identifies 5555555555554444 as MASTERCARD

:) identifies 5105105105105100 as MASTERCARD

:) identifies 4111111111111111 as VISA

:) identifies 4012888888881881 as VISA

:) identifies 4222222222222 as VISA

:( identifies 1234567890 as INVALID
    expected "INVALID\n", not "INVALID CARD\n..."

:( identifies 369421438430814 as INVALID
    expected "INVALID\n", not "INVALID CARD\n..."

:( identifies 4062901840 as INVALID
    expected "INVALID\n", not "INVALID CARD\n..."

:( identifies 5673598276138003 as INVALID
    expected "INVALID\n", not "INVALID CARD\n..."

:( identifies 4111111111111113 as INVALID
    expected "INVALID\n", not "INVALID CARD\n..."

:( identifies 4222222222223 as INVALID
    expected "INVALID\n", not "INVALID CARD\n..."
```

Comment: Can't they hint the students already that using *numerical types* for a credit card number is a bad bad idea? Use strings.

Comment: For fixing the last errors you just need to read the task carefully.

Comment: _expected "INVALID\n", not "INVALID CARD\n..."_ Sounds like it wants you to print "INVALID\n" instead of "INVALID CARD\n..."

Comment: Your two-step calculations for `card1` through `card8` don't seem right. You might want to post the original statement of the problem so we can check your implementation.

Comment: <O/T> strongly consider using an array for all your cards rather than 16 individual variables ... if they have already been covered.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the solution as that would violate the principles & spirit of this course. Somebody suggested that you use an array, and this is good advice, but CS50 teaches you that next week so that you know the hard way to do this now, so try to solve this without looking those up.

You should *always* pay close attention to the error messages on your code-checker:

```
*:( identifies 4222222222223 as INVALID
expected "INVALID\n", not "INVALID CARD"*
```

Once you figure out what's wrong there, you can identify that there's something wrong specifically with AMEX and how you've set it to calculate that. Try running through this section using debug50 and see what is being done to e.g. "371449635398431" (which should result in printing out AMEX").

Check how you printf in that section too. It's not to the checker's spec.

Quick advice on style: you're hard-coding. You could write some of this more dynamically, taking advantage of abstraction and for loops just like is being covered this week of the course. These will remove the need for typing out long, easily typo'd numbers and calling numerous ints over and over again, and help you avoid making mistakes & make debugging less mentally demanding. The next few weeks will be harder than necessary without learning well the tools they give you now, especially when you get to onto memory management and recursion.

```
if ((master == 51 || master == 52 || master == 53 || master == 54 || master == 55) && (length == 16))
```

Here, for a non-buggy example, you could make this *much* easier to read and edit by using >= and <=.